# Seq.map and Seq.mapi optimize away side effects when anonymous function returns unit?

Tags: dictionary, f#, seq, side-effects

While debugging a memoization function I found myself trying to find out whether `Seq.mapi` was actually iterating over a sequence, so I replaced an anonymous function with a `printfn` call like so:

```
let x = "test" |> Seq.map  (fun c -> c |> printfn "%c")
```

Quite to my surprise, the side effect of printing to the console never happened, in FSI it simply returned `val d : seq<unit>`. While this result is correct, I had expected the side effect to kick in when the `map` function iterates over the sequence. I.e., when I replace it with `Seq.map id` it works as expected and returns itself.

When I replace `Seq.map` or `Seq.mapi` with `Seq.iter` or `Seq.iteri`, it actually does print the side effect.

Now I *think* this is due to the sequence being lazily evaluated and that F# internally either creates a sequence of closures, or actually does nothing at all until it gets invoked, because if I do `Seq.last d`, it *does* print all the items in the sequence.

Comment: you *think* correctly ;)

Comment: You can also convince yourself of its lazy evaluation by adding the line `for item in x do ()` which will force it to evaluate the items (and spit output to console)

Comment: @AdamKewley another way to convince yourself that this behavior is not an optimization for functions that return unit is to try with a function that doesn't return unit, like this: `let x = "test" |> Seq.map  (fun c -> c |> printfn "%c"; (char (int c + 1)).ToString())`; then this `let y = String.concat "" x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seq` in F# is an alias for `IEnumerable` so `Seq` module functions are mostly equivalents to Linq. And yes they are evaluated lazily.

Comment: Thanks, apparently my assumption was correct and all things considering, I think it was a moment of typical coding blindness. If it weren't for my wrong guess on `unit` result optimization, as phoog mentioned to check with a simple change to the function, I would've seen it sooner.

Comment: PS: I don't think it is correct to consider `Seq` an alias to `IEnumerable`. Yes, it implements `IEnumerable` through a computation builder, but that does not make it an alias.

Comment: @Abel `Seq` is literally and explicitly an alias of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Here's 100% of the source code for it in the Microsoft.FSharp.Collections namespace: `type seq<'T> = IEnumerable<'T>`. The computation builder is just a convenient way of generating an object that implements this interface.

Comment: @JoelMueller, I think I was confusing/confused in my comment. `seq` is an alias to `IEnumerable<T>` (and not `IEnumerable`). `Seq` defined the _module_ and `Seq.map` the function in that module. Perhaps all too nitpicking, and I wrote before thinking it through as my statement is not correct, my comment mentions `Seq`, but the text is about `seq` and then yes, it is just a type alias. I take it the answerer meant to say `seq` and `IEnumerable<T>`. Thanks for keeping me alert.

Comment: Yes, it should be `seq<T>` in the answer. I'll correct this. Thanks!